# Why my .bat script doesn't delete the files when the total count reaches 8 in the folder?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

pushd C:\backups
set top=7
set filespec=*.bak
set counter=0

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b %filespec%') do (
    set /a counter+=1
    if !counter! GTR %top% del /q "%%f"
)
```

I have .`bak` files, if the number of backup files gets more than 7 i.e. 8 then delete the oldest one.

for example

```
 1. bak1.bak      10:01 am
 2. bak2.bak      10:02 am
 3. bak3.bak      10:03 am
 4. bak4.bak      10:04 am
 5. bak5.bak      10:05 am
 6. bak6.bak      10:06 am
 7. bak7.bak      10:07 am
 8. bak8.bak      10:08 am
```

now, the script shall delete then bak1.bak which was taken at 10:01 hence oldest.

Making it

```
 1. bak2.bak      10:02 am
 2. bak3.bak      10:03 am
 3. bak4.bak      10:04 am
 4. bak5.bak      10:05 am
 5. bak6.bak      10:06 am
 6. bak7.bak      10:07 am
 7. bak8.bak      10:08 am
```

so if again a file is added i.e.

`bak9.bak 10:09`

then delete the oldest one i.e. `bak2.bak`

I wrote the script to but it doesn't exactly work that way. What it does is that it only keeps the top 7 records even if the number of files are more than 8 e.g. rightnow i have 13 files and if i run it it will keep only top 7 and rest 6 would be deleted but this needs to happen only if the number of files gets 8 and hence deleting the oldest one hence making them 7 again.

Comment: "it doesn't exactly work" isn't a good problem description. You have the code right there in front of you in presumably a runnable condition. Tell us *exactly* what does happen.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever just udpated, please check.

Comment: Just to be clear on your problem, you're saying that it only keeps the seven oldest files no matter what, right?

Comment: yeah exactly. what i need is to delete only 1 oldest file if the number of files getse 8 hence making 7 again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you aren't listing the files by age, you're listing them alphabetically by filename. In order to list the files by age, you need to use the `/o:-d` option of `dir` in order to sort them from newest to oldest.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

pushd "C:\backups"
set "top=7"
set "filespec=*.bak"
set "counter=0"

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /o:-d %filespec%') do (
    set /a counter+=1
    if !counter! GTR %top% del /q "%%~f"
)
```